# FormsModule: Add to object, only if the value exists

Tags: angular

I have a form that looks like this:

```html
<form action="" #customForm="ngForm">
  <div ngModelGroup="request">
    <input type="text" ngModel name="city">
    <input type="text" ngModel name="country">
  </div>
</form>
```

In my case `customForm.value` returns the following object:

```
{
  "request": {
    "city": "",
    "country": ""
  }
}
```

The object should only include the properties `city` and `country` if their values are not empty.
E.g., the user types **only** the city name, it should look like this:

```
{
  "request": {
    "city": "New York"
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That must be because you are setting some value to ngModel for country/city. You should use it like this: `<input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="country" name="country">`

Comment: Use model driven form, life will be all set buddy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do that.

```js
let data = {
  "request": {
    "city": "New York",
    "country": ""
  }
};

// Filter properties with undefined values.
let entries = Object.entries(data.request).filter(([key, value]) => value);

let result = {
  "request": {}
};

entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  result.request[key] = value;
});

console.log(result);
```

[Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) can also be used if supported.

```
let result = {
  "request": Object.fromEntries(entries)
};
```

```js
let data = {
  "request": {
    "city": "New York",
    "country": ""
  }
};

// Filter properties with undefined values.
let entries = Object.entries(data.request).filter(([key, value]) => value);

let result = {
  "request": Object.fromEntries(entries)
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please notice that `Object.fromEntries()` is only available from ES2019.

Comment: Thanks @AmitB, I'll add an alternative in the answer.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I wanted. Thank you!